# When to use HTML5 in android? when don't use?

Tags: android, html

What are the situations a developer need to use HTML5 in android.

I am bit confused about when to use HTML5 in android. 
I need to develop an application like a report viewer from web server.
In this case i also need to use some Android specific features like service, preferences, receivers, charts (with the help of third party library).

So i am little confused about what are the good situations to HTML in android apps...

Please help me by your suggestions or direct me a better article about this...

Comment: generally it's good to use HTML5 when you want to share your code with other platform. If that's not the case, then I think that native code offers more.

Comment: Thanks @Ran. So how can i access some native features like GPS Wireless. Is it from the html code or asusual i did in android java code.?

Comment: @TrackRuler, for access some native features like gps and wireless , you have to use phone gap , titanium etc.

Comment: @TrackRuler You never have to use HTML5. Everything is possible with the native API while HTML5 can't do certain things.

Comment: @ChiragRaval : Thanks thts d same solution i got from my research. Now i am somewhat clear to use PhoneGap...

Comment: @zapl: Yes i agree that Everything is possible with native API. But the thing is i am looking to do a most favor integration compatible for ios too... So im looking for this solution. Am i right or wrong in my way?...

Comment: There is no right / wrong here. Read e.g. [Multi-platform frameworks followup](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/04/multi-platform-frameworks-followup.html) or [The Pros and Cons of Cross-Platform App Design](http://mashable.com/2012/02/16/cross-platform-app-design-pros-cons/) - If you want your app to work on multiple platforms and you don't have the resources to develop multiple independent apps then go with some cross-platform framework like PhoneGap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read [this pdf](http://www.slideshare.net/retomeier/html5-or-android-for-mobile-development) . You can get better idea where to use html or where to use native android apps.

Comment: Thanks for the above presentation link. Thats quit clear for me now. And i have a Google IO link suggestion from @Warpzit , above pdf and the following video will be the complete combination to give a clear solution for my questions. Here is the link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f2Zky_YyyQ&noredirect=1

Answer (score 3):

Android is to date the platform with many variants of using different browsers: WebKit-based Android browser, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile, Firefox, UCWeb, Google Chrome Android browser.

The default Android browser has some problems with **HTML5**. And the [Chrome for Android](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/02/introducing-chrome-for-android.html) is designed to solve it. It has almost perfectly latest HTML5 support: such as new elements, video –H.264 and WebM support- and audio tags, geolocation, hardware accelerated *canvas* (2D drawing), and all the CSS3 stuff, such as selectors, effects, media queries, transforms, transitions and animations, ect.

But while it's still not very popular because this new browser isn't available yet for Android 2.x and 3.x version, just for 4.x.

Comment: Thanks for the very good information. But i didnt get my answer from your information. Whether i can use or dont, whats your suggestion...

Comment: I mean it depends on the specific browser in which your application is running. Until the most popular browser among Android's users is default Android browser, HTML5 should be used cautiously. But in the future, these problems must be solved through the development of Chrome for Android. And the use of HTML5 will be natural and without restrictions.

Comment: Thank you. i agree that its based on the bowser.